# R error when trying to generate time series with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I’m trying to produce a time series plot with ggplot2 in R for daily weather data to produce lines of maximum temperatures to compare one year against the other on the same plot.

My data looks like:

```
(head)

        date value year DayOfYear
1 2013-01-01     9 2013         1
2 2013-01-02    10 2013         2
3 2013-01-03    12 2013         3
4 2013-01-04    10 2013         4
5 2013-01-05    10 2013         5
6 2013-01-06     9 2013         6

(tail)
          date value year DayOfYear
405 2014-02-09     8 2014        40
406 2014-02-10     9 2014        41
407 2014-02-11     8 2014        42
408 2014-02-12     9 2014        43
409 2014-02-13     8 2014        44
410 2014-02-14    12 2014        45
```

My approach appears to work OK to this extent:

```
Gatmax$Date <- as.Date(Gatmax$date, '%d/%m/%Y')
Gatmax <- transform( Gatmax,             
           Year = format(Date, '%Y'),
           DayOfYear = as.numeric( format(Date, '%j')))
```

But when I go to plot the data with ggplot2:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(Gatmax, aes(DayOfYear, value)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = year)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = year)) +
    scale_shape_identity()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

Strangely, a seasoned R user who is trying to help me does not get the error using exactly the same script to generate a plot. The only difference is that they are using R in Windows whereas I’m using Linux. I don’t think that this is a operating system issue though, as I believe R is platform agnostic.

Any light that can be thrown to enable successful generation of a plot greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should `dput` (a sample of) the version of 'Gatmax' that you use in `ggplot`. googling your error message leads to [**this**](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/791), which may suggest that the data you use differ from the sample in your post.

Comment: would have to try with a data sample, but maybe that does the trick: as.numeric(as.character(Gatmax$DayOfYear)).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a data-related problem.

I used to get the same error message as you i.e., "Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 'from' must be of length 1" but only when I used

```
scales = "free"      # or
scales = "free_y"
```

and yet there were no problems with the default (i.e., no scales specified) or with

```
scales = "fixed"
```

The solution for me was to make sure my data.frame was nice and clean, by removing all NA values from the column with the Y axis data.